# Why doesn't my 'for' loop function work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a slider with my own custom steps with Javascript / jQuery.

Here I am using a `for` loop, but somehow my function only work, when i put a `while` loop inside it.

**First code *(Didn't work)*:** *- without a `while`*

```
var steps = '';

// Setting up the steps according to the number of slides
for( var i = 0; i < $itemsCount; ++i ) {

    var step = '';

    // Find step number and step text
    var step_text = $items.eq(i).attr('data-title');

    var step_count = i + 1;

    // current step will have the class 'current'
    var step = i === current ? '<li class="step current"><span data-step="'+ step_count +'">'+ step_text +'</span></li>' : '<li class="step"><span data-step="'+ step_count +'">'+ step_text +'</span></li>';

    i++;
    steps += step;
}

var navSteps = $( '<ul class="steps"/>' ).append(steps).prependTo($slider);
```

**Second code *(Did work)*:** *- with a `while`*

```
var steps = '';

// Setting up the steps according to the number of slides
for( var i = 0; i < $itemsCount; ++i ) {

    var step = '';

    // Find step number and step text
    while (i < $itemsCount) {

        var step_text = $items.eq(i).attr('data-title');

        var step_count = i + 1;

        // current step will have the class 'current'
        var step = i === current ? '<li class="step current"><span data-step="'+ step_count +'">'+ step_text +'</span></li>' : '<li class="step"><span data-step="'+ step_count +'">'+ step_text +'</span></li>';

        i++;
        steps += step;
    }
}

var navSteps = $( '<ul class="steps"/>' ).append(steps).prependTo($slider);
```

It isn't really a problem, but I still wonder why the first one didn't work.

Can anyone please tell me why I have to use a `while` instead the loop?

Comment: I'm guessing `$itemsCount` isn't what you think it is?

Comment: Why do you have a `while` *inside* the `for`?  Why are you doing `i++;` inside the `for`, when you already have `++i` in the `for`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the first one, you're incrementing "i" twice: once at the end of the loop body, and once in the loop header (the `i++` in the parentheses).

When you add the `while` loop, you basically make the `for` loop (mostly) irrelevant, because when the `while` loop exits the value of "i" will cause the `for` loop to exit also.

Comment: `face` + `palm` == `this question`

Comment: Doh!! How stupid can I be. Haha! Of course it's that's why... Thanks for the answer mate :D